# How to test annotation object in the class that implement AbstractModule

Tags: gwt, guice

I got a question regarding binding and annotation.

I have the following class:

```
public class MailFacadeImpl implements MailFacade {

  private final PersonDao personDao;

  @Inject
  public MailFacadeImpl(@Mail PersonDao personDao) {
    super();
    this.personDao = personDao;
  }
```

The PersonDao is annotated with a custom annotation.
I would like to be able to test this annotation inside the class that implement AbstractModule.

here is a piece of code:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<SecurityRulesFactory<Person>>(){}).toProvider(FactoryProvider.newFactory(
    new TypeLiteral<SecurityRulesFactory<Person>>(){}, new TypeLiteral<MailSecurityRulesCrdb>(){}));
```

I would like to have somthing similar to :

```
if(PersonDAO is annotated with(Mail.class) ){
bind(new TypeLiteral<SecurityRulesFactory<Person>>(){}).toProvider(FactoryProvider.newFactory(
    new TypeLiteral<SecurityRulesFactory<Person>>(){}, new TypeLiteral<MailSecurityRulesCrdb>(){}));
}
```

Do you think it's possible?

thx for your help :-)
Have a nice friday!

Comment: I found this: PersonDao.class.isAnnotationPresent(Mail.class). Maybe it works. I'll test.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want your module to do this test. Instead, your module can specify how to get or create an instance of `PersonDao` for injection points annotated with `Mail`:

```
bind(PersonDao.class).annotatedWith(Mail.class).to(EmailAwarePersonDao.class);
```

Note that your `PersonDao.class.isAnnotationPresent(Mail.class)` won't help here, since the `PersonDao` class itself isn't annotated with `Mail`; the parameter to the `MailFacadeImpl` constructor has that annotation. There are ways to test for that, but if you are trying to do that from a Guice module, you're probably doing something wrong.